How to repair a broken ground wire?
I moved into a new house to notice a broken ground wire. There was a new sunroom addition by the previous owner. I found an unlabeled 15-amp breaker going into the outlets in this new addition. When I test all outlets in the house, they are all grounded except those in the sunroom. I suspect this broken wire serves that circuit.
I am wondering how I can repair this. Can I add a 12-gauge ground wire splice? The one in the photo appears to have a green center plus multiple strands around.









Need to take off the front cover (3 screws on each side) and then carefully (because...live wires) take pictures of the ground and neutral bars so we can identify (hopefully) the main ground wire) and trace where it goes.

Thank you for the advice. I added 3 new photos that show the inside of the panel. Anything off here? If so, what action should I take to correct the issue in a hopefully simple manner?

It looks like you have a main ground wire (based on (a) bare, (b) stranded, (c) guessing actual size) going from the ground/neutral bar (right side, across from the 5th row of breakers) to the top, where it stops. It should be continuing through either the main feed hole or another hole to go to ground rods.

Another problem: You have a lot of pairs of neutral wires under single screws. Generally speaking that is not allowed. Paired grounds usually are allowed, but not neutrals. And there is plenty of room on the neutral bars to separate them, so you should definitely do that.

I was hoping that the silver stranded wires connected to the lower left part of the panel are the ground line that goes somewhere. Based on your comment, it is not. I shall run gauge 6 copper line from the left ground/neutral bar to the outside existing ground rod that is just on the other side of the wall outside.

No, this broken wire is possibly a much bigger problem.
There are basically two parts to the grounding system in a house with the usual US (NEC) rules:
Ground wire from each receptacle or device to the main panel.
This take strange paths (because old circuits that weren't grounded can now be grounded by alternate paths) but usually means one of:

Metal conduit continuous from panel to receptacle or device
Bare wire in cable from panel to receptacle or device
Bare or green wire in conduit from panel to receptacle or device
Ground wire by itself (bare or green) from receptacle or device to another receptacle or device grounded with one of the first three methods.

If that grounding is done properly then a three-light-tester will light the correct two lights and a resistance/continuity check between the neutral and ground pins on a receptacle will show very low resistance. Unfortunately, there can be miswired receptacles or circuits that will appear to show proper grounding, but if you don't detect proper grounding then that typically means the ground wire is missing, broken or (most common) not properly connected at one end or the other.
The first step in checking a receptacle that does fails a grounding test is to turn off the breaker and open up the receptacle to check the wiring, as the most likely place for a problem is in the receptacle box.
Ground wire from the main panel to one or two ground rods and/or metal water pipe
This is the possible problem shown in the pictures. You have a ground rod that used to have a ground wire and now it has just a stub of that wire. There are actually three possibilities, and it is important to get this checked. But it is NOT the source of your ungrounded receptacles. In fact, this affects all circuits in the building but you can't easily test it - the test is to find the main panel ground wire. This wire/rod is very important in helping protect your entire electrical system in the event of nearby lightning strikes and other problems.

Old rod replaced with new rod - This is quite common, particularly if the main panel was replaced, especially if the main panel was actually moved at some time. Check the main panel and you should find a relatively large bare or green wire going from the ground or neutral bar by itself (not as part of a cable or group of wires in conduit going to a device or receptacle) outside to at least one ground rod.
Wire damaged - If you find that ground wire in the panel but it never quite makes it to a ground rod then you have a serious problem. In that case, this may be the correct ground rod, but the ground rods themselves are relatively inexpensive so the normal thing to do would be to install a new ground rod.
Old rod replaced with Ufer ground - This is basically grounding via concrete. It is required in many locations for new buildings but not for updates of old buildings. However, it is possible that when the sunroom was built that an Ufer ground was installed and that it replaced the ground rod. If that's the case then the ground wire from the main panel will go to the foundation of the sunroom, and that's fine.

If the rod was properly replaced (new rod or Ufer) then why is the old rod there? Inertia/laziness. The electrician didn't want to take the extra few minutes to pull out the old rod and toss it.

OP states house outlets test as grounded, but the outlets in the sunroom do not.  Assuming all outlets are wired correctly(big assumption),  should not all test the same?

@crip659 Agreed Which is why I said the most likely place for a problem is in the receptacle box - e.g., a loose or disconnected ground wire. But I included all the stuff about ground rods because that's what the pictures are all about.

Thanks for the feedback. I checked one outlet in the sunroom and yes, the ground wire is not connected. I shall connect those soon. Back to the disconnected ground rod, I am hoping that it is abandoned. I added a few photos from the control panel. Not easy to locate the ground wire.
